# How can I check that a JTextField has something in it?

Tags: java, swing

I am doing a presence check and I want some code to run if all 10 of my JTextFields are filled in. How could i do this? thanks. This is in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the fields are in a list

```
int emptyIndex = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
   String text = list.get(i).getText();
   if(text.length() == 0){
       emptyIndex = i;
   }
}

if(emptyIndex == -1)
  //there is no empty text fields
else
 // the empty text field is list.get(emptyIndex)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to just loop thru all the fields and call field.getText() and check the return != null and a length > 0.

Answer (score 2):

Put all the JTextFields into an array or `ArrayList<JTextField>` and iterate through the list checking:

```
// assuming an ArrayList of JTextField called fieldList:
boolean filled = true;
for (JTextField field : fieldList) {
  if (field.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
    filled = false;
  }
}

// if filled true, then all fields are filled
```

Comment: @user3317045: I'm the one going to be a pain, but I'm going to decline as I think that you really should give it a try first. This is little more than Java 101. If you need help on creating arrays or ArrayLists, check Google for some of the many tutorials that are available on the subject. Luck!

Comment: i can do normal arrays, just in my program i am confused as to your answer. Do i replace where you have written field?
I have done
field[] fieldList ={tfQ1,tfQ2,tfQ3,tfQ4,tfQ5...};
I am just struggling on this bit and do not understand, i have managed the entire of my other program on my own

Comment: @user3317045: There's no way to answer your question without more context. It looks like you'll need to ask a new and separate question on this site. Please do create and post a [minimal, compilable runnable example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the JTextFields into an array or  `HashMap<JTextField,Boolean>` and iterate through the list checking:

```
// assuming an ArrayList of JTextField called fieldList and the boolean values are by default true:
boolean filled = true;
for (JTextField field : fieldList) {
  if (field.getText().trim().equals("")) {
      filled = false;
      fieldList.put(field, new Boolean(false));
 }
}

// you can complete the code here to process the empty field after you have detected each one
```